# How to read Action attributes from JSP fragments included with <jsp:include />?

Tags: jsp, struts2, getter, jspinclude

Trying to call an Action's getter from an included JSP, I get null:

MyAction.java

```
private String message = "The message I want to read...";
public String getMessage() { 
    return message; 
}
```

main.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
       <div> I'm a DIV in main.jsp </div>           
       <jsp:include page="fragment.jsp" />
   <body>
</html>
```

fragment.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<div>
    I'm a DIV from fragment.jsp
    <br/>
    Message from Action: <s:property value="message" />
</div>
```

How can I get the attribute value in JSP fragment ?

Comment: Why not to use `<s:include>` tag?

Comment: Of course you can use `<s:include/>` instead of the raw `<jsp:include/>`. I just wanna share this weird thing i discovered. Thanks for your comment, though, I'll add to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`<s:include value="somePage.jsp">`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/include.html) instead of `<jsp:include page="somePage.jsp"/>`.

If you instead want to stick with `<jsp:include />` , you need to set

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
```

in Struts.xml, and it will work like a charm.

Don't ask me *why*, [this is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/ognl-basics.html), it was a lucky discovery I made some time ago.

Comment: Hmm... strange or funny thing ;-) Can you register an issue to update docs about that? It's some kind of side effect ...

Comment: "It's some kind of side effect ..." I totally agree, this was my sensation :D