# Struts2: Include jsp does not see value stack from the action for the main jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2, action, return-value

Newbie here. I am trying to include jsp page(s) from another jsp that. The main jsp see all action methods but include jsp page does not see the action's value-stack. I am using `jsp:include` but `s:include` requires configuring action, I think.

How can I use same value-stack in all included jsp pages while using single action for the main jsp page.

Comment: Please try and use better english if possible, your question is nearly impossible to understand

Comment: Show your jsp and explain which values you are not getting and where.

Comment: @zack6849 It seems pretty clear to me, just lacks specifics.

Comment: Maybe i just dont know exactly what he's talking about, either way i didnt understand much of it, i assumed it was a language barrier or something, he could just be using shorthand names for things too

Comment: @zack6849 He's including a JSP page and claims to not have access to the value stack--no shorthand names involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not simply forgetting to put

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

on the included JSP pages, I've encountered this problem some times ago, and I've documented my case in this Q&A:

[How to read Action attributes from JSP fragments included with `<jsp:include />`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19425754/1654265)

I've also opened a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4228), recently closed as not reproducible; I think it must be something related to a specific (customized?) environment.

Try [the solution I've used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19425781/1654265) to overcome the problem (the `allowStaticMethodAccess` one) and, if it works, please come back here and post all the details about your application server, so we can reopen the JIRA. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andrea.  now have more confidence in struts2!